# Как указать Haml следить за файлом и автоматически его компилировать в HTML при любом изменении?

Tags: html, haml

Подобная возможность есть в Sass, которая задаётся командой в командной строке:

```
sass --watch input.scss:output.css
```

Простая подстановка файлов с расширением ".haml" в данную конструкцию положительных результатов не принесла.

P.S. Документацию/руководство по Haml читал, ответа на свой вопрос не нашёл. Буду рад ссылке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLI сборщик haml не умеет следить за файлами, как это делает Sass с параметром `--watch`. Для автосборки haml-файлов, вы можете воспользоваться:

1. Программой-сборщиком. Например, [Prepros](https://prepros.io/), [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/).
2. CLI системами сборки. Например, [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/), [Brunch](http://brunch.io/).
3. Генераторами статических сайтов с встроенными сборщиками. Например, [Middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/), [Octopress](http://octopress.org/).
4. Фреймворками для динамических сайтов с встроенными сборщиками. Например, [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/).